# How to Unzip only filenames recursively in many zip files using linux

Tags: linux, ssh

I have multiple zip files inside a directory. In which I want the list of files inside each zip file. I dot want to extract them in the folder.

presently I am able to extract them, after that only I can get the file names. But I don't want to extract the zip files as there is space constraint on the system. Please advice.

Comment: What language are you using? Are you just want to command this in SSH?

Comment: yes in ssh only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have multiple files, then in order to `unzip -l` all of them, you need to pass a quoted wildcard to the unzip tool, or else the shell will expand the wildcard and unzip will receive multiple filenames. So you need to:

```
unzip -l "*.zip"
```

The `"*.zip"` part makes sure that unzip actually receives the `*` character intact.

Comment: Thanks it worked!! now what if i want to use logsave to save the output of this listing to any log file.

Comment: You simply redirect the output: `unzip -l "*.zip" >> logfile.log` This will append the output to `logfile.log`. If instead you want to overwrite rather than append, use `>` instead of `>>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
unzip -l {myzipfile}
```

will just report the contents (filenames)

Comment: thanks For the prompt reply but i am not able to get any result :(